# How can I prove that if $S$ any independent set of $G$ and $G$ is color critical then $ \chi(G−S)=\chi(G)−1$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a *color critical* graph and $S$ any independent set of $G$ then $\chi(G−S)=\chi(G)−1.$

I tried to show that any independent set induce one color, but I cannot match it with the *color critical* hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Since $S$ is independent, if you can color $G-S$ with $k$ colors, then you can color $G$ with $k+1$ colors.